# How do you construct something like ::placeholder:before

Tags: css

Consider the following code

```
<label>
   <input type="text" placeholder="cool placeholder"></input>
</label>
```

What I would like to do is to have an image before the placeholder. When someone starts typing, I'd like the image and placeholder to disappear.

```
  # when nothing is on input

  label: [img] | placeholder

  # when something is on input

  label: something in input|
```

I can do this with a background image on the placeholder.

BUT, the problem is that then the text indicator `|` shows in front of the image.

Is there any way to make the text indicator show after the background image, and once the placeholder disappears, for it to show up on the start of input again?

A css-only answer would be the best -- changing the structure of the html in this case will be quite costly.

Comment: Any chance you can chuck up a quick fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:focus` http://jsfiddle.net/qg0daxdb/

```
input {
    background: url(http://www.google.com/favicon.ico) center left no-repeat;
    background-size: 16px;
    text-indent: 20px;
}

input:focus {
    background: none;
    text-indent: 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 As a side note, if the OP wants to remove background not on focus, but as soon a character is typed in, then the `:valid` selector should be used, although this requires a `required` attribute in the `input` element.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, sorry. As mentioned Using focus is the best option, if it needs to disappear use :valid and required attribute on input. :valid not supported by early versions of IE though. Below the code in case if text field is not required and image has to go on blur. js in involved in this case, sorry for that.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .placeImg{text-indent:20;background:url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/e/2/a/d/1206574733930851359Ryan_Taylor_Green_Tick.svg.thumb.png)no-repeat;background-size:15px;}
    .placeImg.noImg{text-indent:0;background:none;}

</style>

<label>
     <input onkeypress="tryMe(this)" onblur="tryMe(this)" class="placeImg" type="text" placeholder="cool placeholder" ></input>
  </label>

  <script type="text/javascript">

function tryMe(e){

    if(e.value != ''){
        e.className = e.className + ' noImg';
    }
    else
    {
        e.className = 'placeImg';
    };
}

  </script>
```